# How can I convert .fla file to HTML5?

Tags: flash, html5-canvas

I have a `.fle` (flash ads) file and I wanted to convert it into HTML5 not into an SWF file.
I am already using Wallaby by Adobe but it causes an error.
Please tell me how can I do this conversion.

Comment: Perhaps, you can post the error you are talking about when using Adobe Wallaby.

Comment: I haven't tried Wallaby ... have you tried Adobe AnimateCC's conversion function?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the steps described in [this tutorial](http://blogs.adobe.com/animate/converting-your-flash-ads-to-html5-canvas/) using the [Document Type Converter](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/universal-document-type-converter.html).